S3 access via CLI ok but certificate error via Python Boto3
I have been accessing an S3 bucket without any problems from within an Azure VM. Using the CLI console via terminal and I can do it easily. But via boto3/python, I get:

ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate

D:\spendopt\python\scripts\auxiliary>python chk_Intgrtn_distrib_S3.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\james.gil.b.sousa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 466, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\james.gil.b.sousa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 1095, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\james.gil.b.sousa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 730, in connect
    sock_and_verified = _ssl_wrap_socket_and_match_hostname(
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\james.gil.b.sousa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 909, in _ssl_wrap_socket_and_match_hostname
    ssl_sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\james.gil.b.sousa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 469, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(sock, context, tls_in_tls, server_hostname)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\james.gil.b.sousa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 513, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\james.gil.b.sousa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\ssl.py", line 455, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\james.gil.b.sousa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\ssl.py", line 1042, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\james.gil.b.sousa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\ssl.py", line 1320, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1000)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\james.gil.b.sousa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\botocore\httpsession.py", line 464, in send
    urllib_response = conn.urlopen(
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\james.gil.b.sousa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 843, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\james.gil.b.sousa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 449, in increment
    raise reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\james.gil.b.sousa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\util.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\james.gil.b.sousa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 789, in urlopen
    response = self._make_request(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\james.gil.b.sousa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 490, in _make_request
    raise new_e
urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1000)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\spendopt\python\scripts\auxiliary\chk_Intgrtn_distrib_S3.py", line 29, in <module>
    for obj in S3bucketName.objects.filter(Prefix='e1/'):
  File "C:\Users\james.gil.b.sousa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\boto3\resources\collection.py", line 79, in __iter__
    for page in self.pages():
  File "C:\Users\james.gil.b.sousa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\boto3\resources\collection.py", line 169, in pages
    for page in pages:
  File "C:\Users\james.gil.b.sousa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\botocore\paginate.py", line 269, in __iter__
    response = self._make_request(current_kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\james.gil.b.sousa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\botocore\paginate.py", line 357, in _make_request
    return self._method(**current_kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\james.gil.b.sousa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 569, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\james.gil.b.sousa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 1005, in _make_api_call
    http, parsed_response = self._make_request(
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\james.gil.b.sousa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 1029, in _make_request
    return self._endpoint.make_request(operation_model, request_dict)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\james.gil.b.sousa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\botocore\endpoint.py", line 119, in make_request
    return self._send_request(request_dict, operation_model)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\james.gil.b.sousa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\botocore\endpoint.py", line 200, in _send_request
    while self._needs_retry(
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\james.gil.b.sousa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\botocore\endpoint.py", line 360, in _needs_retry
    responses = self._event_emitter.emit(
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\james.gil.b.sousa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\botocore\hooks.py", line 412, in emit
    return self._emitter.emit(aliased_event_name, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\james.gil.b.sousa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\botocore\hooks.py", line 256, in emit
    return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\james.gil.b.sousa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\botocore\hooks.py", line 239, in _emit
    response = handler(**kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\james.gil.b.sousa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\botocore\retryhandler.py", line 207, in __call__
    if self._checker(**checker_kwargs):
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\james.gil.b.sousa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\botocore\retryhandler.py", line 284, in __call__
    should_retry = self._should_retry(
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\james.gil.b.sousa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\botocore\retryhandler.py", line 320, in _should_retry
    return self._checker(attempt_number, response, caught_exception)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\james.gil.b.sousa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\botocore\retryhandler.py", line 363, in __call__
    checker_response = checker(
                       ^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\james.gil.b.sousa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\botocore\retryhandler.py", line 247, in __call__
    return self._check_caught_exception(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\james.gil.b.sousa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\botocore\retryhandler.py", line 416, in _check_caught_exception
    raise caught_exception
  File "C:\Users\james.gil.b.sousa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\botocore\endpoint.py", line 279, in _do_get_response
    http_response = self._send(request)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\james.gil.b.sousa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\botocore\endpoint.py", line 383, in _send
    return self.http_session.send(request)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\james.gil.b.sousa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\botocore\httpsession.py", line 491, in send
    raise SSLError(endpoint_url=request.url, error=e)
botocore.exceptions.SSLError: SSL validation failed for https://coedados-s3-naturaeco-us-east-1-integration-distribution-prd.s3.amazonaws.com/?prefix=e1%2F&encoding-type=url [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1000)

I've already tried disabling the certificate requirement but the bucket seems to require it.

Hi... If you can fix the question, insted of showing everything, just show the error and the part of the code that give you the error... Also, use the ` to put code
